# how to get the values from model and how to use in controller

Tags: codeigniter

How to get the values from model and how to use in controller? I am trying to fetch email id from database sending the email. I am not getting the email filed value.

Here is my code as below

**controller code**

```
function NAME(){

     $resultt = $this->Products_model->delete_mail($id);
     $data['productemail'] = $resultt->email;

     $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';

     $config['smtp_host'] = 'mail.himagri.com';

     $config['smtp_port'] = '587';

     $config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';

     $config['smtp_user'] = 'info@himagri.com';

     $config['smtp_pass'] = 'Himagri@123';

     $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';

     $config['newline'] = "\r\n";

     $config['mailtype'] = 'html'; // or html

     $config['validation'] = TRUE; // bool whether to validate email or not      

     $this->email->initialize($config);
     $this->email->from('info@himagri.com', 'Himagri');
     $this->email->to('xxxx@gmail.com');//i want to use email id

     $this->email->subject('test delete mail');

     $body = $this->load->view('deletemailer', $data, TRUE);

     $this->email->message($body);


     $this->email->send();

     echo $this->email->print_debugger();

     $this->product_display($data);
 }
```

**Model code**

```
 public function delete_mail($id) {
       $this->db->select('*');
       $this->db->from('supplier_registration');
       $this->db->join('approve_products', 'supplier_registration.id=approve_products.supplier_id_fk');
       $this->db->where('approve_products.id', $id);
       $query = $this->db->get();
       return $query->result();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$query->row();` because you are fetching one row only

```
public function delete_mail($id) {

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('supplier_registration');
        $this->db->join('approve_products', 'supplier_registration.id=approve_products.supplier_id_fk');
        $this->db->where('approve_products.id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->row();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

return the result from the model as follows :

```
return $query->row();
```

and call this function in controller and fetch the data.

```
$resultt = $this->Products_model->delete_mail($id);
$data['productemail'] = $resultt->email;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding spaces on your join tag as checked on the documentation https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

`$this->db->join('comments', 'comments.id = blogs.id');`